# How to use stored procedure for the CommandText of UpdateCommand?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a DataGridView for editing a table. The following code is using to update the table.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("...."))
{
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from T", con);
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;

    da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
    // da.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "exec sp1 @p1, @p2, @p3...";
    da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
    da.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
    da.Update(datatable.GetChanges());
}
```

I found that `da.Update(datatable.GetChanges())` smartly generates minimal set clause according to the modified columns.

```sql
update T set c1 = @p1 where K = @p2 -- If only c1 is changed in the grid 
update T set c1 = @p1, c2 = @p2 where K = @p3 -- if both c1 and c2 is changed
update T set c4 = @p1 where K = @p2 -- if only c4 is changed
......
```

How to write the stored procedure for the `CommandText`?

Comment: Where did the stored procedure come in?

Comment: Basically I need to merge the changes in the grid into the table. Or is it possible to write SQL Server 2008's `merge` in the UpdateCommand.CommandText?

Answer (score 4):

You will want to create a stored procedure on the server that receives the parameters.  The method you are using is for generating SQL and does not use stored procedures, it sends SQL thru the connection to the server.  If I named the sproc UpdateSomeUserTable:

```
oleDbCommand1.CommandText = "UpdateSomeUserTable";
oleDbCommand1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

oleDbCommand1.Parameters["us_id"].Value = "668987";
oleDbCommand1.Parameters["us_lname"].Value = "White";
oleDbCommand1.Parameters["us_fname"].Value = "Johnson";

oleDbConnection1.Open();
oleDbCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
oleDbConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: The `SqlDataAdapter.update` method automatically generate multiple SQL statements according to the changes in the grid. How to let the adapter use the stored procedure?

Comment: You can't use the automatic update feature since it generates SQL.  You will need to configure the rows for editing and then capture the data to post it back to your procedure.

Comment: Should the capturing be done at DataGridView UI layer? Or at the DataTable bound to the DataGridView? It seems the first one is better structured?

Answer (score 0):

This is a code smelling, I do not advise use, but it works.

```
dataAdapter.RowUpdating +=  (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Command != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Command.CommandText))
    {
       e.Command.CommandText = $"";                                
    }
};
```